# Looking for a word to describe being shot by a sniper

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a verb that characterizes being shot by someone from a hiding place, perhaps at long range, like a sniper?

Comment: "I was sniped by the guy hiding in the tree. He sniped me." It's not standard, but kids use it all the time in video games.

Comment: "Picked off" comes closest to what I am grasping for.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the word shot, for this. It is actually what you have described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*snipe* is exactly the verb you are looking for.  My Chambers dictionary gives two shades of the verb, neither has any hint that it's a slang or childish word.

> **intransitive verb**
>   1. to shoot snipe [the bird] for sport
>   2. to shoot at individuals from a position of (usually distant) cover
>   3. to attack or criticize, especially from a position of security
>
> **transitive verb**
>   to pick off by rifle fire from (usually distant) cover

Comment: This doesn't quite work. OP is looking for a term which focuses on the target, not the sniper. Mitch suggests you can "be sniped" but this is not supported by this answer's definitions or examples.

Comment: "Picked off" seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *sniped* being helped by an auxiliary *be* verb. Do not confused with *snipped*, which is the past participle of snip.

**Example:**

> He was sniped by an unknown combatant.

Note that *sniped* can also be used in reference to the person sniping. But you won't need the auxiliary verb in most instances.

**Example:**

> He sniped the enemy from a very long distance.

Answer (score 0):

*Assasinate* means the target was specifically chosen.

> to murder (a usually prominent person) by sudden or secret attack often for political reasons

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assassinate)

Comment: I am afraid that is too broad, as it is not gun-specific.